# BadPasswordException with correct password

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a password protected pdf file which I try to open with itextsharp. I know the correct password but when I call

`var pdfreader = new PdfReader(file, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password));`

I get `BadPasswordException` (Bad user password) with the following stacktrace:

```
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(IRandomAccessSource byteSource, Boolean partialRead, Byte[] ownerPassword, X509Certificate certificate, ICipherParameters certificateKey, Boolean closeSourceOnConstructorError)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(String filename, Byte[] ownerPassword, Boolean partial)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(String filename, Byte[] ownerPassword)
```

Adobe Reader opens the file as expected. itextsharp version 5.4.3.0

This is how the security details of the document look like:

[image: This is how the security details appears]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the OWNER password and not the USER password?

Comment: @ChrisHaas: I use the password that I enter in Adobe reader when I open the file.

Comment: But do you enter the user password or the owner password?

Comment: Just out of curiosity would setting PdfReader.unethicalreading = true help at all?

Comment: @SteveL: Tried but didn't help.

Comment: Do you know how this PDF was created? I can't think of a way to restrict page extraction _without_ using an `owner` password but according to your screenshots there isn't an `owner` password and only a `user` password.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: The screenshot says that there is "Document Open Password" set

Comment: The "Document Open Password" is Adobe Acrobat/Reader's way of saying "user password". The "Permissions Password" is the same as "owner password".

Comment: You are using `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password)`, may it be that the password of the PDF is encoded in UTF-8 and `Default` is not a UTF-8 encoder? Try `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)`